# Only store/retrieve last line from prompt in expect_out buffer

Tags: bash, shell, tcl, expect

I wrote the following expect script:

```
    set prompt {$}
    set domain $::env(METEOR_DOMAIN)
    puts "$domain"
    spawn meteor mongo "$domain"  --url
    set pass "mypassword"
    expect {
        Password: {
            send "$pass\r"; 
        }
    }
    expect $prompt
    puts "The output is '$expect_out(buffer)'."
```

and the puts command outputs:

```
 The output is ' mypassword

 mongodb://client:56099867-e806-3a7a-e5b4-93127e0a3b42@production-db-a1.meteor.io:27017/db_meteor_com'.
```

which I imagine is what is in the buffer, but I only want the second part (e.g.) the mongo string

How do I make expect only put the last part the buffer or only retrieve the last part in the buffer for storage in an environmental variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off `stdout` output before the password, and turn it back on afterward.  Furthermore, you can parse the output and extract the mongo string. Here is one way to do it:

```
log_user 0
spawn ...

expect "Password:" {
    send "mypassword\r"
}
log_user 1

...

if {[regexp -line {^mongodb:.*$} $expect_out(buffer) url]} {
    set url [string trimright $url]
    puts "URL is: '$url'"
}
```

According to the documentation, `log_user 0` will turn off `stdout`, and `log_user 1` will turn it back on.

Comment: turning stdout off then on did not seem to work, but parsing with reg exp sure did! Thanks!